# Not showing any wireless network controller in lspci -nn

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, broadcom, adapter

If I ran `lspci -nn` in my new desktop then showing

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9b53] (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9bc8] (rev 03)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43ed] (rev 11)
00:14.2 RAM memory [0500]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43ef] (rev 11)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43e0] (rev 11)
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43d2] (rev 11)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43bc] (rev 11)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43b2] (rev 11)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4388] (rev 11)
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:f0c8] (rev 11)
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43a3] (rev 11)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43a4] (rev 11)
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Device [1d79:2263] (rev 03)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 16)
```

No wireless controller showing . I am using internet with a usb connection with my phone.

My motherboard is gigabyte h510m h and processor is intel i5 10500. I have a tenda wifi adaptor but it is not working in ubuntu 20.04. What can I do? Fast boot is disabled. I am using only ubuntu 20.04 , not windows (erased when install ubuntu).

Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:b711 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0e8d:2004 MediaTek Inc. Primo HM5
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 09da:c10a A4Tech Co., Ltd. USB Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 09da:2268 A4Tech Co., Ltd. USB Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Are you certain the wireless network adapter is PCI-based? Does it appear in `lsusb`?

Comment: sorry for long time load shedding. if i type lsusb then showing  Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:b711 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0e8d:2004 MediaTek Inc. Primo HM5
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 09da:c10a A4Tech Co., Ltd. USB Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 09da:2268 A4Tech Co., Ltd. USB Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: Based on the `lsusb` output, have a Realtek RTL8188GU [that is really hit-or-miss with Ubuntu](http://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=usb:0bda-b711). A quick search online shows some 3rd-party drivers on GitHub, but I don’t have any reliable way to know if they’ll solve your problem 

Answer (score 0):

[It seems](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188gu/issues/4#issuecomment-635463081) there is no way to make it work in your system.
Setting up an Ubuntu VM in a Win 10 host may work.

You would be probably better off getting a different WiFi adapter than spending time on this endeavor.